# Fast way to preform a function on all pair combinations of elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, networkx, python-itertools

Here is a simplified version of a function that I have:

```
def create_edge(a,b,network=G):
    weight = calculate_weight(matrix[a],matrix[b])
    network.addedge(array[a],array[b], weight = weight)
```

Basically it takes two matrix row-indices, calculates the weight between the two rows and then adds it as the weight for the edge between two nodes.

My goal is to preform this function on every pair combinations in an array. What I mean by this is that if I have an array as such:

`array = np.array(['A','B','C','D'])`

to preform these functions:

```
create_edge('A','B')
create_edge('A','C')
create_edge('A','D')
create_edge('B','C')
create_edge('B','D')
create_edge('C','D')
```

The catch is my array is large! It contains roughly 15000 elements. This means it is very slow. I'm wondering if there is a quick way to do this?

---

What I have tried so far:

To prevent a [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). I probably should note that I don't necessarily need it to be pair combinations as B->A and A->B are the same, I just gathered it would be faster after doing this:

```
def create_network(network):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array)):
            create_edge(i,j,network)
```

I also tried this:

```
comb = list(itertools.combinations(array,2))

def create_network(network):
    for i in range(len(comb)):
         create_edge(comb[i][0],comb[i][1], network)
```

Either case was too slow. I understand that's likely due to the size of my array but I'm sure there is a faster/more effective/better method to do this.

Comment: As long as the "goal is to preform this function on every pair combinations in an array." then there *is no faster way*. Fundamentally, you are forced to use a quadratic algorithm. You aren't going to get much faster than `itertools.combinations` in Python...

Comment: I see, I was hoping that there might be a way to vectorize the problem or something along those lines? Possibly some intelligent mathematical approach?

Comment: Not unless there's some kind of correlation underpinning the values that you could use to slim down the number of calculations required. Otherwise you'd probably be interested in parallelisation, rather than vectorisation.

Comment: @neophlegm 

Interesting. If I was to take a parallel route, how would I approach it?

Comment: @artbn My guess would be to use `processes`, since for `CPU` intensive tasks, `python` threads might not be very useful.

Comment: @neophlegm Vectorization will not change the underlying complexity of your algorithm, it will only shave off (albeit sometimes dramatically in the case of `numpy` vs vanilla Python) constant factors.

Comment: what might save some memory is not creating the list, and iterating over the combinations directly  (`for x, y in itertools.combinations(array,2): create_edge(x, y, network)`)

Comment: @Maarten Fabré 

Didn't think of that. Thanks will try it out!